# git-ftp command failed to complete when using Git Submodules in Jenkins

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, git-submodules

We have a project in Laravel that is in a repository and that uses a package also developed by us that is in a different repository.

**Problem:**
As we make changes to any of the Package's designs, these are not obtained by the project that uses it.

**Solution:**
Use a git function which is the submodules.

**Procedures:**
We are using Jenkins for CI CD, this works perfectly. When trying to add the Git Submodule from the pack package to the laravel project repository, Jenkins was unable to complete when trying to execute the git-ftp commands.

**Methods used in jenkins:**

```
git config git-ftp.url "ftp://myserver.com/public_html/"
git config git-ftp.user "''' + username + '''"
git config git-ftp.password "''' + password + '''"
git config git-ftp.syncroot .
git ftp push --auto-init
```

**The procedure:**
Add the submodule in the repository, command:

```
git submodule add -f https://myuser@bitbucket.org/mycompany/thepackage-library.git packages/mycompany/packagelibrary/src
```

The error obtained after adding the git submodule was:

```
. . .

fatal: Commit found, use 'git ftp push' to sync. Exiting...
1 file to sync:
[1 of 1] Buffered for upload 'packages/mycompany/packagelibrary/src'.
Handling submodule sync for packages/mycompany/packagelibrary/src.
fatal: Could not get last commit. Use 'git ftp init' for the initial push. Access to resource denied. This usually means that the file or directory does not exist. Wrong path? exiting...
Could not push packages/mycompany/packagelibrary/src, trying to init...
fatal:  Access to resource denied. This usually means that the file or directory does not exist. Wrong path? exiting...
fatal: Failed to sync submodules., exiting...
fatal: Commit found, use 'git ftp push' to sync. Exiting...
3 files to sync:
[1 of 3] Buffered for upload '.gitmodules'.
[2 of 3] Buffered for upload 'packages/mycompany/packagelibrary/src'.
Handling submodule sync for packages/mycompany/packagelibrary/src.
fatal: Could not get last commit. Use 'git ftp init' for the initial push. Access to resource denied. This usually means that the file or directory does not exist. Wrong path? exiting...
Could not push packages/mycompany/packagelibrary/src, trying to init...
fatal:  Access to resource denied. This usually means that the file or directory does not exist. Wrong path? exiting...
fatal: Failed to sync submodules., exiting...

. . .
```

The expected behavior is that git-ftp obtained commits from both repositories to be sent to the server.